# 4017 beginning with Q1, not Q0

Tags: integrated-circuit

I am using a 555 timer in astable mode to clock a 4017, for some reason, the first output to become high is Q1, not Q0. Do I have a faulty chip? It's definitely wired up correctly, which checked numerous times.
Here is a video of it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wveTqKnOH8

Comment: Show us a circuit diagram

Answer (score 3):

To get a 4017 (and most any other similar parts) to start off in a known state requires you to **provide a reset** pulse at power-up. You have simply grounded the reset input so it is never reset to a known state. It could start up in **any of 32 possible states**.

The best way to do that is to use a supervisory chip such as a [DS1812-5+](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1812.pdf).

If you don't really care much about reliable reset under all conditions 
you can also use an RC circuit. Eg.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg9JpS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will work okay if the power supply rise time is short, and there the capacitor discharges during the off time (an additional dummy load on Vdd may be required to speed that process if other elements don't provide that load). So it won't work for slow rise time or short interruptions of power, or other similar non-clean power-ups.

Comment: also failure to connect VCC to the 4017 can give unexpected behaviour,